# Improperly formatted json file causing issues in my terminal

Tags: json, bash

I was messing around in files I shouldn't have been in order to edit my bash shell to make it look nice. I downloaded bash_it and followed this tutorial to do this (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/jazz-up-your-bash-terminal-a-step-by-step-guide-with-pictures-80267554cb22). However, now all I see in my shell is this at every line:

```
Expecting ',' delimiter: line 39 column 2 (char 2196)
Expecting ',' delimiter: line 39 column 2 (char 2196)
```

So then I go and add a comma to the end of the file I think is the source of the problem (`default.json`) which looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Default color scheme for shell prompts",
    "groups": {
        "hostname":         { "fg": "brightyellow", "bg": "mediumorange", "attrs": [] },
        "environment":      { "fg": "white", "bg": "darkestgreen", "attrs": [] },
        "mode":             { "fg": "darkestgreen", "bg": "brightgreen", "attrs": ["bold"] },
        "attached_clients": { "fg": "white", "bg": "darkestgreen", "attrs": [] }
    },
    "mode_translations": {
        "vicmd": {
            "groups": {
        "hostname":         { "fg": "brightyellow", "bg": "mediumorange", "attrs": [] },
        "environment":      { "fg": "white", "bg": "darkestgreen", "attrs": [] },
        "mode":             { "fg": "darkestgreen", "bg": "brightgreen", "attrs": ["bold"] },
        "attached_clients": { "fg": "white", "bg": "darkestgreen", "attrs": [] },

        "gitstatus":                 { "fg": "gray8",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
            "gitstatus_branch":          { "fg": "gray8",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
            "gitstatus_branch_clean":    { "fg": "green",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
            "gitstatus_branch_dirty":    { "fg": "gray8",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
            "gitstatus_branch_detached": { "fg": "mediumpurple",    "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
            "gitstatus_tag":             { "fg": "darkcyan",        "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
            "gitstatus_behind":          { "fg": "gray10",          "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
            "gitstatus_ahead":           { "fg": "gray10",          "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
            "gitstatus_staged":          { "fg": "green",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
            "gitstatus_unmerged":        { "fg": "brightred",       "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
            "gitstatus_changed":         { "fg": "mediumorange",    "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
            "gitstatus_untracked":       { "fg": "brightestorange", "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
            "gitstatus_stashed":         { "fg": "darkblue",        "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
            "gitstatus:divider":         { "fg": "gray8",           "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] }
        },  
        "mode_translations": {
            "vicmd": {
                "groups": {
                    "mode": {"fg": "darkestcyan", "bg": "white", "attrs": ["bold"]}
            }
        }
    }
},
```

And then I get another error that pops up in terminal

```
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 39 column 3 (char 2197)
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 39 column 3 (char 2197)
```

So I add double quotes and it expects another comma, and more quotes, etc...

Ideally I would simply like to be able to use my terminal again without these json errors being at every line.

Comment: There are many online json validators.  Have you tried to use any of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are indeed many JSON validators online, like this one: https://jsoncompare.com/#!/simple/

However, I use my own offline unix tool **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)**, using a debug option (`-d`), it's easy to spot the locus within JSON where problem is (thus one can use that tool as a JSON validator too).  In your case, adding a comma at the end of JSON is wrong, as normally any nested JSON must be closed either with `}` or with `]`. So once the trailing comma removed, the tool gives this output:

```
bash $ <default.json jtc -d
.read_inputs(), reading json from <stdin>
.parsejson(), exception locus: ...          }|        }|    }|}|
.location_(), exception spot: --------------------------------->| (offset: 2421)
jtc json exception: unexpected_end_of_string
bash $
```

`unexpected_end_of_string` at the end of JSON may mean only one thing: there are missing brackets `]` or `}`. In your JSON there are no missing un-closed arrays (all of them are closed `[]`), thus it's only closing curly brace(s) `}` is missed.

Adding one by one at the end until JSON started parsing (added 2 in total):

```
bash $ <default.json jtc -d
.read_inputs(), reading json from <stdin>
.write_json(), outputting json to <stdout>
{
   "groups": {
      "attached_clients": {
         "attrs": [],
         "bg": "darkestgreen",
         "fg": "white"
      },
      "environment": {
         "attrs": [],
         "bg": "darkestgreen",
         "fg": "white"
      },
      "hostname": {
...
```